# Want to redirect root of my website to load with subdomain www

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have hosted my Nextjs app on AWS Amplify. When a user loads the rootdomain of my website i want them to be redirected to the sub domain.

Example :
If someone enters example.com in the browser I want them to be redirected to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

I have attached the rewrites and redirect configurations in the Apps settings of my AWS Amplify app settings.

These configurations are not working, kindly highlight if I am missing anything.

[image]

Comment: Add a cname dns record to www to direct to the root

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to resolve this by moving my 301 redirects to the top of the list.